# Pickle EOFError: Ran out of input in pygame

Tags: python, sockets, pickle, eoferror

I am trying to make a multiplayer game in pygame, using socket and pickle. So far I have set a Server-Network file and a file which executes the main game. When trying to pass information tho, this error occurs:

```
  File "D:/Coding/online game/game.py", line 24, in main
    p2 = n.send(p)
  File "D:\Coding\online game\network.py", line 27, in send
    return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Here is my code:

```
import socket
import pickle

    class Network:
        def __init__(self):
            self.client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            self.server = "192.168.1.10"
            self.port = 5555
            self.addr = (self.server, self.port)
            self.p = self.connect()
            print(self.p)

    # Other stuff, not causing the error

    def send(self, data):
    try:
        self.client.send(pickle.dumps(data))
        return pickle.loads(self.client.recv(2048))
    except socket.error as e:
        print(e)
```

Then, I have the variable:

```
p2 = n.send(p)
```

And when I run it the error occurs. What am I doing wrong? I'd appreciate any help.